# Does an FX loop send have the same output volume as the input?

Tags: amplifiers, guitar-effects, electric-bass-guitar

I play an active bass (Peavey Cirrus) and have recently rediscovered my envelope filter (DigiTech Bass Synth Wah X-series).  I've been wanting to incorporate it in my sound again but I remember from using it in the past that it seems overly sensitive to my bass.  I can turn the sensitivity all the way down and it will still react.  I assume this is due to the boosted output of the active electronics.  If I reduce the gain from my bass then I have to turn up the amp to compensate the overall volume.  That doesn't work for mid song use or while improvising.  I haven't had enough patch cables to connect through my effects loop yet to try it out but I'm hoping it can help.

So, will using the effects loop on an amplifier compensate for my active bass and allow the sensitivity of the envelope filter to act more normally?

Edit: The problem is that my pedal is volume sensitive and I am curious if the volume of the effects send is increased, decreased or the same.  Is the effects loop effected by the preamp gain or eq?

Comment: I've read this question a few times, and I'm still unclear on what exactly you're asking and the context.  From what I understand, one solution that comes to mind would be to have a channel pedal that would allow you to set different volumes for different channels on your amp.  That way, when you use your FX, you change the channel for the volume you want to compensate for your active electronics.  That said, I could be way off.  Perhaps edit?

Answer (score 1):

The effects loop on an amp.is where the pre-amp and post amp. are joined, or interrupted. The pre-amp has all the eq. in it, and the post is usually just a power amp.So, yes, I think the fx will be coloured by any tone changes made on the pre-amp., which is pretty standard. By starting with every pot flat, theoretically there would be no colouration. If you plugged straight into front of amp., there will still be a change of tone, as the signal goes into the pre-amp.

Comment: So the question has more to do with how the gain takes place for the volume sensitive pedal.